# Can't create file object using pathlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib

My code is something like this:

```
from pathlib import Path

def make_dir(dirr):
    if Path(dirr).exists() == False:
        Path.mkdir(dirr)
 

make_dir('output')
```

'output' directory doesn't exist. When I'm trying to create it, I get errors, including `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_closed'`.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of `if x == False` do `if not x`

Comment: Path.mkdir doesn’t work like that. You meant to do `Path(dirr).mkdir()`

Comment: in this case x is equal to True ?

Comment: No, just write `if not Path(dirr).exists():`

Comment: oh, you right, it works! In official python docs there is no examples of Path(dirr).mkdir() , thats why it was difficult for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`Path` is a class, providing methods to call on its instances, not a module full of functions. `Path.mkdir(dirr)` only works if `dirr` is already a `Path` (and even when it works, it's a silly way to spell `dirr.mkdir()`). Just convert to `Path` once up front and use the `Path` instance repeatedly:

```
def make_dir(dirr):
    dirr = Path(dirr)
    if not dirr.exists():
        dirr.mkdir()
```

Or more simply, just convert and [use `mkdir` directly with `exist_ok`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.mkdir) (available since Python 3.5) to avoid the need for a test and check before making the directory:

```
def make_dir(dirr):
    Path(dirr).mkdir(exist_ok=True)
```

Comment: Nice and clean. I'd add that `os` module also has a `makedirs` function that can be used with the `exist_ok` argument and enables to create nested directories, if needed.

Comment: @MatBBastos: `Path`'s `mkdir` supports creating the parents as well. If they don't want object-oriented paths, then yeah, `os` and `os.path` have you covered, but there are some advantages to using `pathlib` from a code "flow" perspective. I'm particularly a fan of them overloading the `/` operator for path concatenation. :-)

Comment: I completely agree, the concatenation is very handy, and `pathlib` does a good job in giving intuitive understanding with the use of `Path`s.
I'd also use your solution! My comment was just for the sake of completeness in the subject ;P